# What is the easiest way to print all prime numbers until n, in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, primes

What kind of algorithm should I use, for printing all prime numbers until let's say 1000?

SQL Server is preferred.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an appropriate problem for SQL.

Comment: Create a table of all prime numbers up until some limit. Select from it.

Comment: I second @GordonLinoff, first its not an appropriate problem for SQL second, this is not the way to ask your assignments on SO

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47680/29325 — and I second @MartinSmith: we are not a "Do my homework" site.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it's actually not that hard: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=386eaf76411c4a3a07b2df81160c1b7c

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Try that in SQL Server, lol.  I didn't say it wasn't possible.  It is just the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @sergiol, This is nor a homework, neither an assignment. It is a Hackerrank problem, that I am doing on my free time.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this to list all primes that smaller than 1000 in SQL

```
;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT 2 AS Value 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Value+1 AS VAlue 
    FROM temp t
    WHERE t.Value < 1000
)
SELECT * 
FROM temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT 1 FROM temp t2
                WHERE t.Value % t2.Value = 0 
                AND t.Value != t2. Value
            )
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/XNTNK18089)

Answer (score 1):

This code I've written for SQL Server is very fast, it will find all the primes less than 10 million in about 12 seconds:

```
DECLARE @Min int = 2, @Max int = 100000
--
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#N','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #N
--
CREATE TABLE #N(N int NOT NULL, SqrtN int NOT NULL);
--
  WITH L0 AS (SELECT 'Anything' N FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) AS T(N)), -- 16 values
       L1 AS (SELECT A.N FROM L0 A, L0 B, L0 C, L0 D, L0 E, L0 F, L0 G, L0 H), -- 15^8  values (2562890625 more than enough for max value of int (2^31-1)
       L2 AS (SELECT TOP(@Max/6) CONVERT(int,6*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) RowNum FROM L1)
INSERT INTO #N(N, SqrtN)
SELECT T.N, SQRT(N)
  FROM L2
 CROSS APPLY(VALUES(L2.RowNum-1),(L2.RowNum+1)) T(N)
 WHERE T.N BETWEEN @Min AND @Max
   AND 0 NOT IN (N%5,N%7,N%11,N%13,N%17,N%19,N%23,N%29,N%31,N%37,N%41,N%43,N%47,N%53,N%59)  -- Not interested in anything dividable by these low primes
--
ALTER TABLE #N ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
--
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Primes','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Primes
--
SELECT Z.N Prime
  FROM (SELECT N FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(5),(7),(11),(13),(17),(19),(23),(29),(31),(37),(41),(43),(47),(53),(59)) T(N)
         WHERE T.N BETWEEN @Min AND @Max
         UNION ALL
        SELECT X.N
          FROM #N AS X
         WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                            FROM #N AS C
                           WHERE C.N <= X.SqrtN 
                             AND 0 = X.N%C.N)) Z
 ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

Assuming you already have following table *populated* with data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PrimeNumber(Num INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

you'll need only a simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.PrimeNumber
```

Comment: Hint (see section **[The first 1000 prime numbers]**): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer
I did it in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @number INT = 4
DECLARE @isprime INT = 0
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX) = '2&3&'

WHILE (@number <= 1000)
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 2
    WHILE (@counter <= CAST(SQRT(@number) as INT))
    BEGIN
        IF (@number % @counter = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @isprime = 0
            Break
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @isprime = 1
            SET @counter += 1
        END        
    END
    IF @isprime = 1
    SET @result += CAST(@number as VARCHAR(6)) + '&'
    SET @number += 1
END

PRINT(LEFT(@result, len(@result)-1))
```

This is the output

2&3&5&7&11&13&17&19&23&29&31&37&41&43&47&53&59&61&67&71&73&79&83&89&97&101&103&107&109&113&127&131&137&139&149&151&157&163&167&173&179&181&191&193&197&199&211&223&227&229&233&239&241&251&257&263&269&271&277&281&283&293&307&311&313&317&331&337&347&349&353&359&367&373&379&383&389&397&401&409&419&421&431&433&439&443&449&457&461&463&467&479&487&491&499&503&509&521&523&541&547&557&563&569&571&577&587&593&599&601&607&613&617&619&631&641&643&647&653&659&661&673&677&683&691&701&709&719&727&733&739&743&751&757&761&769&773&787&797&809&811&821&823&827&829&839&853&857&859&863&877&881&883&887&907&911&919&929&937&941&947&953&967&971&977&983&991&997

Answer (score -1):

```
with prime
as
(
select 1 as 'start'
union all
select start+1 'start'
from prime where start<100
)

select e as prime_value  from
(select  a.start%b.start  as w, a.start as e from prime A  , Prime B
where --a.start% b.start<>0 and 
 b.start<a.start
--and a.start between 1 and 100
)A
where w=0
group by A.e 
having count(w) <=1



BY Nagaraj M-BE
```

Comment: You should put some explanation to your answer otherwise it will be hard to understand future users.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @range int = 1000, @x INT = 2, @y INT = 2 

While (@y <= @range)
BEGIN
 while (@x <= @y) 
 begin
    IF ((@y%@x) =0) 
    BEGIN
        IF (@x = @y) 
            PRINT @y
            break
    END
 IF ((@y%@x)<>0)   
 set @x = @x+1
 end  
set @x = 2
set @y = @y+1 
end
```